# A function that satisfies the $n$-th derivative where $x=0$ is $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: functions, derivatives, generating-functions

Is there a function that satisfies $f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{1}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$?

Comment: There are infinitely many "essentially different" such functions, but only one upto scalar shift if we assume analyticity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume $\forall n\geq 1$, then I gather any primitive of $f(x) =\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ should do.

The rationale behind it is to find a power series $F$ with $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$ (and non-zero radius of convergence) satisfying what you want. That is,
$$
F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n\cdot n!}.
$$
Deriving this, you get
$$
F'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n!} = \frac{e^x-1}{x}.
$$

Comment: If one allows [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(e%5Ex-1)%2Fx) to pick the antiderivative, one comes up with $\int_\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx = \text{Ei}(x)-\log x+C$ where $\text{Ei}(x)$ is the exponential integral. (This is essentially just a definition.)

Comment: Works perfectly, plus brilliant explanation, that was actually what I was asking the question for, that power series, I didn't know you could just take the derivative, I guess it makes sense.

Comment: If the radius of convergence is $r>0$, then everything works as one would hope (differentiation termwise, etc.) in $(-r,r)$. Note that they may actually only be a single power series that "works" for you -- the one for which $F(0)$ is well-defined (?).

Comment: Quick question, how did you know to start the power series at 1 and not zero?

Comment: Only to avoid a division by zero, I'd say.

Answer (score -2):

There infinitely many of them... obviously as long as the function is $n$-times differentiable and $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$ you can always multiply constant to modify it to be $1/n$. One example is $e^x/n$

Comment: No, you misunderstood. n is not a constant. The n in 1/n and the n in the n-th derivative are the same.

Comment: You forgot that this should hold for **every** integer $n$, not just for one of them.